# Column standardized form of a matrix

Tags: r, data-analysis

How can I standardized a matrix by column. I'm trying to achieve the same result as scale(matrix). Here's my implementation, it gives different result from the scale function when the column is > 1.

```
standardize <- function(X)
{
  stan <- (X - mean(X))/sd(X)
  return(stan)
}
A = matrix( c(2, 4, 3, 5), nrow=2)
standardize(A)
scale(A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think you might need `apply()` like below

```
apply(A, 2, standardize)
```

- or you can write you `standardize()` like

```
standardize <- function(X) apply(X,2, function(v) (v - mean(v))/sd(v))
```

and then you are able to use

```
standardize(A)
```

which works the same as `scale(A)`